# Is python module loading is thread safe in Google App Engine

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Google App Engine implements custom module loader.

Is this loader is thread safe?

Mean that loading module from one thread will lock loading this module from another till will be loaded - want avoid reload in middle?

Answer (score 1):

[Python imports are threadsafe](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code), I don't see a scenario where the AppEngine team decide to break it.

Comment: It is good with load of modules since it saves coding time.

As I understand reloading of module is not thread safe since it could replace variable in the middle?